# Scripts working only after the first time source is loaded by $ ajax in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I wrote a simple **$ajax** request like this:

```
 ladowanie = jQuery.ajax({
     timeout: 5000,
     cache: false,
     type: "GET",
     url: target,
     dataType: "html",
     beforeSend: function(){
         jQuery('#loader').stop().fadeIn(200);
         jQuery('.mainSurv').hide();
     },
     success: function(result){
         jQuery('.mainSurv').show();
         jQuery('#loader').stop().slideUp(200);
         jQuery(".mainSurv").html(result);
         jQuery(".mainSurv").slideDown(500);
     },
     error: function(result){
         if(result.statusText != 'abort'){
             jQuery('#loader').hide();
             jQuery('.mainSurv').html('<div id="errorMsg" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; color: #e00;">Przepraszamy, połączenie nie powiodło się, wybierz ankietę ponownie lub naciśnij F5.</div>');
             jQuery('.mainSurv').css({'display':'block'});
         }
     }
  });
```

The target url is the **html** file with script's inside the  HTML tags.
When I call **ajax** function first time all scripts are working fine but if I recall this function all loaded scripts stop working.

This problem concerns only Firefox browser, work properly on Opera, IE, Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Is `ladowanie` the function? Try to specify `ladowanie` is a function:

```
 ladowanie = function(){
     jQuery.ajax({
         ...
     });
 }
```